# Trying to use glide and volley to get an image from a URL, getting an error onResponse method

Tags: android, android-volley, android-glide

The Code goes as follows which is giving me an error of `onResponse` method:

```java
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
// Url for the API call
String url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        String url = response.toString();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.MemeImageView);

        Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this without saving it into a new string. Just check the response first whether it is null or not and also whether the response contains the "url" attribute and then use response.getString("url") directly in imageview in your case.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
             if(response!=null && response.getString("url")!null){
Glide.with(this).load(response.getString("url")).into(findViewById(R.id.MemeImageView));
}
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() ....
```

Comment: Glide.with(this) is showing error on "this"

Comment: You are using this from onsuccess listener, you can either use getApplicationContext() if you are inside activity or use getActivity() if you are using fragment. Glide here requires context which can be provided as written above.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check the Response of your request.

Here it is:

[image]

You are converting the whole response to a string and passing it as a URL in Glide. but you only need the image URL from this response.

So Your image URL should be like this:

```
String url = response.getString("url");
```